# Nuxt discard grandparent component

Tags: nuxt.js

My nuxt pages structure is as below:

```
|-pages/
|-- parent.vue
|-- parent/--index.vue
|          --child.vue
|          --child/--index.vue
|                  --grandchild.vue
```

when i go to `/parent/child`, it is something like this

```
_____________________
|parent             |
|   _______________ |
|   |child          |
|   |               |
|   |               |
---------------------
```

and `/parent/child/grandchild`:

```
_____________________
|parent             |
|   _______________ |
|   |grandchild     |
|   |               |
|   |               |
---------------------
```

but I want grandchild to display full page, like below

```
_____________________
|grandchild         |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
---------------------
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Firstly, I may be mistaken but what's the difference between `parent.vue` and `parent/--index.vue`, it's the same thing no? Also, for your question, can you remove the grandchild at the top level of the `pages` directory? You only want a specific path, right? Or you really need to nest it inside of `parent` for some reason? Also, did you looked into layouts? `parent` is maybe a layout that you can just not display. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views